# addEventListener function works at the beginning without being fired

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So here are my HTML codes:

```js
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing());
function testing() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="good"; 
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Place Order" id="sub"/>
    </fieldset> </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Q4.js"></script>
```

In which I declared a button to submit the form. 
I added an event to the submit button to run the function `testing()`. 
I expected that when the user clicks on the button submit, the page will prompt "good". But, as soon as I load the page, "good" already appeared without clicking in the button.
[result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZuTN.png)

Why does this happen?

Comment: In the `.addEventListener()` call, `testing()` should be just `testing`. Your code as it stands *calls* the function and then passes the return value to `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: JavaScript evaluates arguments eagerly. If you have `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is called first and it's return value is passed to `foo`.

Comment: The duplicate uses jQuery, but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove parentheses to prevent function `testing()` to be executed. Just put the name of the function.

You can find more details and simple [example of listener here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Add_a_simple_listener).

Here is a **working snippet** :

```js
/*file javaScript Q4.js*/
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing);
function testing() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="good"; }
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Place Order" id="sub"/>
</fieldset> </form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Q4.js"></script>
```

*You can also put your function directly into your listener, like this :*

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="good"; 
});
```

> About the bug that "show the `good` word for a second only" :
>   *Clicking the button causes the form to be submitted, which means the page reloads or the loads the URL in action. That means that all
>   temporary changes that JavaScript made in the current page load are
>   gone.* Thanks [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

Comment: I tried to do so. But then it's kinda weird. I clicked "place order" then I saw the "good" pop up for 1sec and then disappears again. So is that a problem from my browser?

Comment: @Duke_ngn That's a bug that probably came from another part of your code. Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or more code ? :)

Comment: There is nothing much left in my codes. The button is in a fieldset of a form. The other parts are just a table and a textbox.

Comment: The Q4.js contains only those 3 lines ?

Comment: What browser are you using ? Is my snippet showing you the same bug ?

Comment: Yes. Cause I am just playing around with innerHTML and EventListener function

Comment: I am using google Chrome on my Mac. I don't know why but your snippet is totally perfect !

Comment: Nice then, try to clear your cache and restart your browser, I'm also using Chrome on MacOS :) If answers helps, don't forget to `plus` them and mark one of them as `answer`.

Comment: @Duke_ngn: *"The button is in a fieldset of a form."* Clicking the button causes the form to be submitted, which means the page reloads or the loads the URL in `action`. That means that all temporary changes that JavaScript made in the current page load are gone. The example here works likely because you posted incomplete HTML and thus the button isn't actually inside a `<form>`.

Comment: Oh @FelixKling you're right of course ! I'll add your precisions to the answer and credit you.

Comment: so what if i still want to include my button inside my form. What should I do to prevent the page to be loaded again and causes that problem ?

Comment: Here is some help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664680/7415107

Answer (score 2):

Change this line :

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing());
```

to

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing);
```

Answer (score 2):

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function accept two parameters

1. Event name
2. Callback function
3. options (optional)

So you had called function inspite of passing function reference there.

Write it down to like below

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing);
```

**OR**

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", function testing() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="good"; 
})
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there any reason to still name the function if you're using it as a closure?

Comment: @War10ck yupe, you can see the function name in stacktrace, easy to understand what you're being debugging and better readability :)

Comment: Great point! I didn't think of that. +1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need parenthesis.

`document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", testing);`

Comment: you mean parenthesis